# Error with PhantomJS when installing Highcharts export server on Azure VM (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: azure, highcharts, dotnethighcharts

I'm trying to install the Highcharts export server on a new Azure VM that runs on Ubuntu 20.04. I've installed node.js and npm, and when I try to run the npm install command:

```
sudo npm install highcharts-export-server -g
```

I get the following error:

```
Download already available at /tmp/phantomjs/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
Verified checksum of previously downloaded file
Extracting tar contents (via spawned process)
Removing /usr/local/lib/node_modules/highcharts-export-server/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom
Copying extracted folder /tmp/phantomjs/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2-extract-1634831384140/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64 -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/highcharts-export-server/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom
Phantom installation failed { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, link '/tmp/phantomjs/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2-extract-1634831384140/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64' -> '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/highcharts-export-server/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom']
errno: -13,
code: 'EACCES',
syscall: 'link',
path:
'/tmp/phantomjs/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2-extract-1634831384140/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64',
dest:
'/usr/local/lib/node_modules/highcharts-export-server/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom' } Error: EACCES: permission denied, link '/tmp/phantomjs/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2-extract-1634831384140/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64' -> '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/highcharts-export-server/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom'
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! phantomjs-prebuilt@2.1.14 install: node install.js
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the phantomjs-prebuilt@2.1.14 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! /root/.npm/_logs/2021-10-21T15_49_48_318Z-debug.log
```

Here is a screenshot:
[image: Screenshot of error]

I've also tried installing PhantomJS seperately using this command:

```
sudo npm install -g phantomjs@2.1.1 --unsafe-perm
```

(See: [Why can't I install phantomjs (Error: EACCES: permission denied)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46338286/why-cant-i-install-phantomjs-error-eacces-permission-denied))
That didn't help.

How can I get past this error and install highcharts on our VM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by updating NPM and nodejs to latest versions